# Jquery mobile loads correctly in Firefox, but not Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery, jquery-mobile

I created a mobile site in html and jquery, but it is not loading properly in Chrome (or on an iphone).  There is no backend to the site - all changes to content would happen right through editing the html.  Inside of my html, I made no specific reference to ajax.  And, each page links through "#pageid.  The problem is that as I navigate the site, various pages do not display correctly unless I hit "refresh."  URL is mobile.shorelinelake.com. I am VERY new to this, so please be patient with a newbie :)  Thanks for any help!

http://mobile.shorelinelake.com  (if you click through to "Lake" and then "Sailing," or "Cafe" to "Menu," you can see the problem - the page jumps after loading, cuts off the header, places content below the footer, or will entirely hide jquery elements...)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed right away is that your using an old version of Jquery and Jquery Mobile. There have been alot of improvements since the alpha that you are using. Also you are linking to a few files that aren't there. Phonegap.js and ajax-loader.gif for some reason are not found. In my console I see 196 warnings that I believe are all related to you using old versions.

Also you have 31 html errors. One example is here

line 88:

```
<a href="tel:16509657474" div data-role="button" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn-text">
```

You have alot of stranded `</p>` tags. Most of them are in the menu page. Fixing these errors is necessary to troubleshoot your problem. Try running your document through an html5 validator to find these mistakes.

I also recommend breaking this into smaller pieces. Here is my reasoning:

1. Easier to maintain and edit.
2. Keep the dom size reasonable. Jquery will remove the old pages from the dom keeping it very manageable.
3. Faster page loading resulting in a better user experience. Your user will probably not be going to each page. Only load what they need to see.
4. Bandwidth could be costing your user extra money on a mobile device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have a version of the site saved locally on my computer that I think references different jquery versions. But, I'm faced with the same problem of pages not loading properly. I used dreamweaver to create the template, though, so I am not sure how to update my references to the current jquery files.  Also, when I tried to break the site into several docs, and I would use <a href="lake.htm"> for example, I would ALWAYS get an error loading the page, as it keeps trying to direct me to /index#lake instead of /lake.htm.  Do you know why this might be happening?